# Can't Use CookieContainer on my request, only hand made cookie works :\

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest, html-agility-pack

I'm working on another project where i use http web requests.
Currently i'm using cookie containers on some requests, but i found that it doesn't work on this specific request.
I'm making a site change it's page by an http request for each page it finds and download info I want from it, but since the page url is hidden, and if you press to go back in the browser it doesn't go to the page before it goes to the homepage.

I found that the body of the request can change the page and it worked when i used the cookie  I got using fiddler. But since i tried the cookiecontainer the info on all the pages are the same as the 1st page.

```
            for (int i = 2; i <= _TotalPag; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    int _pagina = i;
                    HttpWebResponse response3;
                    HttpWebRequest request3 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(lista_links_categorias[cbo_categorias.SelectedIndex]);

                    request3.KeepAlive = true;
                    request3.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36";
                    request3.Accept = "*/*";
                    request3.Referer = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
                    request3.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.6");

                    CookieContainer cookieContainer3 = new CookieContainer();
                    request3.CookieContainer = cookieContainer3;

                    request3.Method = "POST";
                    request3.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

                    string _body;
                    if (i == 2)
                    {
                        _body = @"M%24M%24sM1=M%24M%24sM1%7CM%24M%24lPH%24lCPH%24cCatBrw%24cPL%24btPagCommd&__EVENTTARGET=M%24M%24lPH%24lCPH%24cCatBrw%24cPL%24btPagCommd&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE_KEY=cafb3561-af6f-4e78-bc31-b71166377d8e&__VIEWSTATE=&txtQ=&orderby=DisplayName&orderby=ASC&produtos=21&orderby=DisplayName&orderby=ASC&produtos=21&hdnPrdListData=1%24%242&hdnCatalogBrowser=&txtEmail=&txtPass=&__ASYNCPOST=true&";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _body = @"M%24M%24sM1=M%24M%24sM1%7CM%24M%24lPH%24lCPH%24cCatBrw%24cPL%24btPagCommd&__VIEWSTATE=&txtQ=&orderby=DisplayName&orderby=ASC&produtos=21&orderby=DisplayName&orderby=ASC&produtos=21&hdnPrdListData=1%24%24" + _pagina + "&hdnCatalogBrowser=&txtEmail=&txtPass=&__EVENTTARGET=M%24M%24lPH%24lCPH%24cCatBrw%24cPL%24btPagCommd&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE_KEY=cafb3561-af6f-4e78-bc31-b71166377d8e&__ASYNCPOST=true&";
                    }
                    byte[] postBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_body);


                    request3.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
                    Stream stream = request3.GetRequestStream();
                    stream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
                    stream.Close();

                    using (response3 = (HttpWebResponse)request3.GetResponse())
                    {
                        var responseValue = string.Empty;
                        // grab the response  
                        using (var responseStream = response3.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                            {
                                responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();

                            }
                        }
                        if (responseValue != "")
                        {
                            string _txtFileNew = @"xxxxxxxxxx\Pagina" + _pagina + ".txt";
                            StreamWriter _srEannew = new StreamWriter(_txtFileNew, true, Encoding.UTF8);
                            _srEannew.WriteLine(responseValue);
                            _srEannew.Close();

                        }
                    }

                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc3 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                    doc3.Load(@"xxxxxxxx\Pagina" + _pagina + ".txt");
                    HtmlNodeCollection collection2 = doc3.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='produtoGrelha']");
                    foreach (HtmlNode node2 in collection2)
                    {
                        string _ID = node2.Attributes["p"].Value.Replace("/n", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty).Replace("\r", string.Empty).Replace("&nbsp;", string.Empty).Trim();
                        lista_ids_prods.Add(_ID);
                    }
                }
```

Is there any solution that doesn't make me use a specific cookie that needs updates everyday?

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing CookieContainer before your for-loop.

```
CookieContainer cookieContainer3 = new CookieContainer();
for (int i = 2; i <= _TotalPag; i++)
{
    ...
    request3.CookieContainer = cookieContainer3;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, still the same all pages have the same content as the 1st page :\

Comment: Oh, you need to use the same CookieContainer you used for first request.
Set-Cookie header, sent from the first request, is lost if you use new CookieContainer

Comment: Also, make sure domain name for request is the same, otherwise cookies will not be sent.

Comment: I am not using request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie,....) in any of my requests.
I'm using only the CookieContainer. If I set the cookie like i previously did (without CookieContainer and when the requests worked), the cookie would expire and the program would stop working unless i changed the cookie manually on the code, that's why I started using the CookieContainer, in the Homepage Request and 1st page it works, but if I change pages it's like I said, the response will be the same.

Unless the problem is in the old body I'm using since I don't understand it and just changed the page

Comment: I'm not setting the domain either, sry for adding another answer but I didn't have space in the previous comment

Comment: As you can tell from the name, CookieContainer is a container for Cookie objects, which keeps track of cookies between requests and manages cookie expiration. See MSDN Remarks section http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Using CookieContainer can help you emulate browser's cookie container, but just like browser's cookie continer, cookies will expire.

Comment: Ok, I just found out that the body of the request has a need to be updated too in this part:
VIEWSTATE_KEY=48a3c440-bb33-4ec5-8c26-bbee39ab9fe6&
It's a thing that keeps changing according to fiddler, I don't have the knowledge to understand what this viewstate does, can someone try and explain to me what can I do to make these things auto updated?

Thanks

Comment: It might be not relevant to the question, but might help to parse website easier. Try using Selenium (http://scraping.pro/example-of-scraping-with-selenium-webdriver-in-csharp/) to emulate browser. You will only need to search for paging links using XPath and click them with code (no manual interaction required)